# .htaccess file not caching

Tags: htaccess, apache, cache

I have read several guides for how to write the htaccess file for caching but with no success. I asume I wrote something wrong and need some help on finding what i did wrong. Here's my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# 1 YEAR - doesn't change often
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav)$">
Header set Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate, max-age=31536000"
</FilesMatch>

# 1 WEEK - possible to be changed, unlikely
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate, max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>

# 3 HOUR - core content, changes quickly
<FilesMatch "\.(txt|xml|js|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate, max-age=10800"
</FilesMatch>
```

The non-www to www rewrite is working fine btw

Comment: Any cache over 4-12 weeks is kinda pointless. Most browsers will clear their cache before this. Most likely your host does not support the files match method.

Comment: well it doesn't harm :-)

Comment: The `FilesMatch` directive is a core directive - I'm not aware of hosts not supporting this? (Can hosts disable this, providing .htaccess files are allowed?) However, `FilesMatch` matches physical files on the filesystem, so if you are internally rewriting to files with a different extension then it's possible these directives won't match. (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the mod_expires syntax using something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 week"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Finally it works! I've been struggling with this for the last week+. Thanks a lot Simon!

Comment: I see `text/x-javascript` used a lot in this context, but shouldn't this be `application/javascript` for most modern servers? Was `text/x-javascript` _ever_ in common usage? I can find very little on this supposed mime-type. The only place I've seen it used is in examples of `ExpiresByType` such as this?

Comment: Hey @W3d, yep your totally right, there seems to be some confusion what should be used in the htaccess.  `text/x-javascript` was experimental and `text/javascript` now obsolete in MIME type. `application/javascript` supersede `text/javascript`, but, Apache seems to understand at least the ones in my code. I'll test the later code and update the answer if it works.